# How to solve "destructuring. Missing annotation" in FlowType?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

The following code:

```
export const myFunction = ({ option1, option2 }) => {};
```

...gives:

```
destructuring. Missing annotation
```

I do not want to have to create a `Type` specifically for the options object supplied to `myFunction` - this seems unnecessary, adds noise to the code and and will be a maintenance headache - can I achieve this and eliminate this FlowType error, or is this "how FlowType works"?

Answer (score 1):

There is an inline syntax:

```
export const myFunction = ({ option1, option2 }: { option1: string, 
    option2: Array<string> } ) => {};
```

Looks horrible to my eye - if you want static typing, use a statically typed language?

Comment: _use a statically typed language?_ - yes, probably. For example, Javascript doesn't have pure functions. As a result each function call invalidates type refinements (like `if (typeof x === "string") {}`). Within the brackets flows infers that `x` is a `String`. But as soon as you call a function within the block, the type refinement is invalidated and you'll quickly run into type errors.